# Is there a Launchy or Quicksilver for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Eclipse/Windows, and it would make things go faster to be able to push alt-space, type the first few letters of a filename, and jump to that file. I've been googling for productivity tools, and now have a half a dozen new Eclipse plugins, but nothing that does this one thing.

Does such a plugin/tool exist, or a combination of macros one could use to fake it?

The closest I've found so far is [InstaSearch](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch). Maybe it's possible to modify it to include file names. [Ctrl-Shift-R](https://rayfd.wordpress.com/2007/05/20/10-eclipse-navigation-shortcuts-every-java-programmer-should-know/) also seems to help, though having to enter a * in the beginning to do generic search puts a damper on the party. [GoToFile](http://www.muermann.org/gotofile/) won't install on 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to open a Class within your project, you can use CTRL+Shift+T and type your class name or use camel case. CTRL+SHIFT+R will find other files within your workspace.